# How to select from multiple tables when some of the tables are empty in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch data from 5 tables(all columns of each table) all have FK, which is PK of single table.

But some of the tables may have record may be empty.If data is present on the respective column/table it should return otherwise null/default value

There is one to many and one to one relations on the child tables with parent table.

I have tried so far 
 - UNION which has concern of same number of columns
 - CROSS JOIN not returning any data
 - SELECT ALL_COLUMN FROM ALL_TABLE WHERE TABLE.FK=ID Not returning any data
 - LEFT JOIN working for 2 tables but not more than that

```
SELECT A.GENDER, B.BLOCKED_USER FROM t_macroworld_registration AS A 
LEFT JOIN t_macroworld_blacklist AS B ON 1=1 WHERE A.ID=15
```

What are the possible ways I can implement this in a view in MySQL.

Comment: Can you try using multiple LEFT JOINs? Also, what's your expected behavior when you join tables with one-to many relationships?

Comment: I am expecting to return all the rows of dependent table for that specific id  with repeated rows of parent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved It,
I broke the whole thing into many select query based on FK from each table, so number of additional row returns and mapping has become easy.

Who ever is getting this kind of problem, if it is possible then break it into many select query instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Outer join operations are the normative pattern...

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN c ON c.a_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN d ON d.a_id = a.id
 WHERE a.id = 15
```

It's important for the predicates on the outer joined tables to be in the `ON` clause and not the `WHERE` clause. If there's any predicate in the WHERE clause requires that a value from one of the outer joined tables be non-NULL, that will negate the "outerness" of the join, making it into an inner join.

The "big rock" problem with this the result when there are more than one matching rows in b, c and d.  If there's five rows from b that match, and three rows from c that match, and two rows from b that match, it's going to look like a lot of duplicates. (5x3x2 = 30 rows to be returned, with a lot of duplicated data on those rows.)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
 w.id,w.name,a.address,i.name,i.quantity
FROM
 warehouse w
 LEFT JOIN address AS a ON a.warehouse_id = w.id
 LEFT JOIN item AS i ON i.warehouse_id = w.id
 LEFT JOIN order AS o ON o.item_id = i.id
WHERE
 w.id = 1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Will give you an overview of your stock and orders for your warehouses. This will also duplicate some results. 
Assuming 2 warehouses, 1 address for each, 3 items per warehouse, 2 orders by item = 2 * 3 * 2 = 12 lines

I recommend adding your `LEFT JOIN` stage by stage and visualizing the result for each stage. You'll quickly understand why lines are multiplying.
Note the usage of foreign keys and ids in the tables to link the tables.

Good luck